# Azure Media Service stream is not exportable for AVFoundation

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.ios, avfoundation, azure-media-services

Using Azure Media Service I am streaming video for 1-10 seconds to mobile clients which have to playing in loop in different views including UICollectionView. To display video I am using **AVPlayer**.
Now I want to cache it. I am trying to export video after it loaded using **AVAssetExportSession** but `asset.Exportable` return false so it shows error:

> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this
>   media.}

Is there any way to save and cache video stream from azure media service, I've tried different formats but non of them is exportable. Here is how I craete asset:

```
var urlManifest = http://***.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/***.ism/manifest;
var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(
    NSUrl.FromString(String.Format("{0}(format=m3u8-aapl)",urlManifest)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if AVPlayer exposes a way to cache the fMP4 chunks from the server, but a workaround may be to use Azure Media Services' progressive download to grab the video, if that works for your scenario.